# Will using a pure MQTT approach be the right decision?

Tags: java, architecture, rest

I plan to provide additional functions for a closed-source **3rd party point of sales** application. That application is used in restaurants, is run on Windows and uses dbase style databases. I know the details about the database structure (hey, it's **DBase**, so no big deal ;-)) and am able to read and correlate tables.

The application is run behind a **firewall** neither I nor most of the clients can influence, so opening incoming ports on the firewall is not possible.

The additional functions I provide shall be either used in an externally hosted **web application or an App** on a smartphone (**iOS or Android** does not matter here, I will most likely use Apache Cordova for this)

My problems is *getting the data **out***. In my current design / architecture I plan to use MQTT to publish data from the customers site to a server located on the Internet where it can be retrieved by the App / application.
Unfortunately I have no experience with **MQTT** and do not know if it would be better to take a different approach / alternative and only use MQTT for publishing data and add an additional REST layer for the application / App.

Here is my **criteria** for making MQTT the "right decision"

- support **authentication** for publishing and retrieving data (no one
  shall be able to forge data or retrieve data for a site he or she is
  not entitled to see)
- use as little **bandwidth** as possible (both my server and the dataplan for the smartphone running the App have a limit and I or the user will be charged for bandwidth used beyond that limit)
- be a good fit for various and complex **JSON** structures (from the picture you can see which kind of information I want to transport, they can be several kilobyte in size)
- support retrieving data using **REST** (I read that MQTT can be used from Javascript and in a REST style but have no deeper experience with that)
- allow **signalling of updates** from site to user
- allow **listing** (a user should be able to use REST in order to retrieve a list of sites he is entitled too) and **filtering** (when for example getting details about a clerk the user should be able to set a filter to the name of the clerk)[image]

My biggest question is if MQTT will be usable from the web application / App in an "elegant" way. I could relatively easily add my own REST layer "on the right side of the picture" but I do not want to overcomplicate my design

Comment: I do not know MQTT, but whatever you implement, you will need some kind of protocol, and MQTT does not seem a too bad decision for what you have in mind. So now its time to build a prototype or spike and try it out. If you got some experience from that, you may consider to come back and answer your own question.

Comment: message size limit for mqtt is 260MB so you should be okay